# Trouble with sails lift - TypeError: Cannot call method 'createCollection' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typeerror, sails.js

I am getting the following error when I try to run sails lift on my project:

```
clayton@cfs846631:~/Documents/stream-sync$ sails lift
[Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]]

/home/clayton/Documents/stream-sync/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/adapter.js:77
    connection.createCollection(collectionName, function __DEFINE__(err, r
               ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'createCollection' of undefined
    at __DEFINE__ (/home/clayton/Documents/stream-sync/node_modules/sails mongo/lib/adapter.js:77:20)
at afterwards (/home/clayton/Documents/stream-sync/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/adapter.js:469:7)
at /home/clayton/Documents/stream-sync/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/adapter.js:465:7
at /home/clayton/Documents/stream-sync/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/adapter.js:500:23
at /home/clayton/Documents/stream-sync/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:273:18
at /home/clayton/Documents/stream-sync/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:351:18
at Server.close (/home/clayton/Documents/stream-sync/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:210:38)
at Db.close (/home/clayton/Documents/stream-sync/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:347:21)
at /home/clayton/Documents/stream-sync/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:271:21
at null.<anonymous> (/home/clayton/Documents/stream-sync/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:563:7)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
at null.<anonymous> (/home/clayton/Documents/stream-sync/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:140:15)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/clayton/Documents/stream-sync/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:512:10)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at net.js:440:14
at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:459:13)
```

I have attempted to reinstall sails, and also saw that it might be related to the adapters.js file in config. I updated the mongo adapter to use host: 'localhost'. This project is working fine on my laptop, I am just trying to get it set up on my desktop now, so I am assuming it has something to do with the way sails is set up or missing node modules.

I don't know what else to try at this point.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but are you sure MongoDB server is running?

Comment: I second that--`[Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]]` makes it look like you haven't started the Mongo server locally.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because sails cannot connect to your mongodb server.

```
[Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]]
```

install/start mongodb and sails will lift correctly. If you have trouble to get mongodb running try the official docs http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/